# Извлечь подстроку из строки с помощью регулярки и записать в новое поле документа MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Помогите составить запрос для обновления коллекции. Документ имеет вид:

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ca8f5070d640213fcc9007a"),
    "name" : "FSL",
    "tag" : "sometags",
    "field" : "EQ: HP SERVER S/N: HQ846LG1623 C/C: CHICAGO"
```

Чтобы перенести подстроку после S/N в новое поле и получить вид:

```
{    "_id" : ObjectId("5ca8f5070d640213fcc9007a"),
    "name" : "FSL",
    "tag" : "sometags",
    "serial" : "HQ846LG1623",
    "field" : "EQ: HP SERVER S/N: HQ846LG1623 C/C: CHICAGO" }
```

Делаю вот таким образом, но сваливается в ошибку E11000 duplicate key error collection: index: *id* dup key:ObjectId

```
db.collection.aggregate([ 
{$project: {temp: {$split: ["$field", " "]}}}, 
{$unwind: "$temp"}, {$match: {temp: /regex/i}}, 
{"$addFields": {"serial": "$temp"}}, 
{"$out": "newcoll"} 
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение оказалось простым, чтобы не было конфликтов, нужно пересоздать _id:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$project: {serial: {$split: ["$field", " "]}, "name": 1, "tag": 1, "field": 1, "_id": 0}}, 
{$unwind: "$serial"}, 
{$match: {serial: /regex/}}, 
{"$out": "newcoll"} 
])
```